# How to get uploaded file info in Zend1

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, zend-form

I am new to zend, I am trying to upload a CSV file and get its contents.
My form class is

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Upload extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        // Set the method for the display form to POST
        $this->setMethod('post')->setEnctype('multipart/form-data');

        // Add an email element
        $this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
            'label'      => 'Your email address:',
            'required'   => true,
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            'validators' => array(
                'EmailAddress',
            )
        ));

        // Add the comment element
        $this->addElement('file', 'csvfile', array(
            'label'      => 'CSV File:',
            'required'   => true
        ));


        // Add the submit button
        $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Send Request',
        ));

        // And finally add some CSRF protection
        $this->addElement('hash', 'csrf', array(
            'ignore' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

My controller

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->view->headTitle('WestWing');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form = new Application_Form_Upload();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
                $formData = new Application_Form_Upload($form->getValues());
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($formData);
                $fileName = $formData->file->tmp_name;
                echo $fileName;

            }
        } else {
            echo "anot well";
        }

        $this->view->form = $form;
    }

}
```

but when I do `echo $filename`, it returns me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another form ($formData), you already have $form.